# Can you sell your invention without having it patented?

Tags: patent-agent

I am researching the company Inventhelp to help me sell my invention.

But they don't even provide legal services.

Does that mean that one can sell an invention even without having it patented?

Comment: Before using any invention promotion company I would recommend a study of the history of such firms and a look at the USPTO and FTC sites for reports of problems. And your question seems disjointed - I do not see any logical connection between InventHelp not offering legal services and you being able to sell a product without patents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "sell the invention" you mean sell products that utilize the invention  then the answer is probably yes. You have to determine if your product infringes on any existing active patents, but if not, nothing stops you from selling the product. Nothing also stops someone else from selling a copy of your product.

If, however, you want to sell the invention itself to a company who would then manufacturer and sell a product the answer is less clear. Without a patent, there is nothing preventing the company from manufacturing the product without paying you. Also, since there is no way from preventing other companies from copying the product, your invention it is less financially attractive to a company.

What a lot of small companies and inventors do is to file a provisional patent application. These are easier and cheaper to file. This buys you one year in the US to then try to sell the invention to a larger company or otherwise raise funding. If you get money for your invention, you or the company can then file a non-provisional patent application to protect the invention.

Answer (score 1):

"Can I sell my invention without a patent?" is a frequent question but somewhat of a non-sequitur. Patents do *not* provide a right to do anything at all other than the right to try to stop others ?from doing something. Your patents are not relevant to you selling something, it's other's patents that can be an issue stopping you from doing so.

If your question  is about licensing your invention without a patent I would have said no, you have nothing  to license  but you can  read the books of Steven Key - One Simple Idea and  Sell Your Ideas With or Without A Patent and others. He has dozens of patents but is well known for his thesis that you only need perceived ownership to license an idea and can get you licensee to essentially pay for your patent. It sounds crazy but have heard him speak to inventor groups several times and he is very persuasive.

Comment: I suspect the question is about selling the IP, but your answer is certainly relevant.

Comment: Thanks I improved the answer